# Laravel Filesystem error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Dears,
since my last update my Laravel (running v5.2) backend is not working at all.

Yesterday I had created a Unit Test and run *vendor/bin/phpunit* to see how unit testing works in Laravel.
However, after running *composer update*, Laravel was completely screwed up. Basically now inputs coming from any route via POST/GET/... don't reach controllers.

If I insert a *dd(Input:all())* in any controller, it will show up a blank array. The strange thing is that I don't get any error, neither in laravel.log nor in the display (despite having the .env set up to debug).

Lastly, the Validators seem to be working and when the execution flow reaches one, I get the validation errors being displayed.

How to fix this error? Or where should I look for further details to investigate about it?

Thanks

Comment: What if you execute `dd($_GET)` or `dd($_POST)`. Do you get any values? Also try to execute `composer dumpautoload -o`

Comment: I get an empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well probably there is a problem with writing logs or some other files.

Pleas chceck directory permissions as it's written [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation#configuration). This depends of corse of the server/OS that you're using.

You maybe forget about something or didn't check it from the last update.

Comment: if I insert a var $a = 0/0 or a trailing coma I immediately get an error displayed and a .log reporting the error

Comment: depends where... you said that you won't get anythink in controller - so maybe you cannot write: `bootstrap/cache` directory with `services.json`

Comment: The strange thing is that I have been developing this backend for three months and never got a permission issue. I am on OSX, updated to El Capitan a month ago